# ERROR in Multistyles...Module not Found (Angular-cli.json)

Tags: angular-cli

**Running into this error:**

```
ERROR in multi styles
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/rgspatel/Documents/Seed_CASS/ui/src/app.css' in '/Users/rgspatel/Documents/Seed_CASS/ui/node_modules/angular-cli/models'
 @ multi styles
```

**My Attempts**
- These files are supposed to be .scss however my guess is that CLI is not being able to use scss? Encountered the same issue when trying to use Google Materials previously

**app.css**

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/variables.css";
@import "app-base.css";
```

**app-base.css**

```
@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";

$topnav-background-color: #222;
.user-avatar {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
}
#toggle-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 23px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
.btn:focus{
    outline: 3px auto #FFF;
}
.topnav{
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: $topnav-background-color;
  padding : 6px;
    z-index:2;
    .text-center{
        text-align: center;
        padding-left : 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .top-right-nav{
        .buy-now{
            a{
                color:#999;
            }
        }
        .dropdown-menu{
            top: 40px;
            right: -5px;
            left : auto;
            .message-preview{
                .media{
                    .media-body{
                        .media-heading{
                            font-size: 14px;
                            font-weight: bold;     
                            margin-bottom : 0;  
                        }
                        p{
                            margin : 0;
                        }
                        p.last{
                            font-size : 13px;
                            margin-bottom: 0;
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
            hr {
                margin-top: 1px;
                margin-bottom: 4px;
            }
        }
    }

}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar{
  border-radius: 0;
  position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 50px;
    left: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: -225px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: $topnav-background-color;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    .list-group{
        a.list-group-item{
            background: $topnav-background-color;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a:hover{
            background: darken($topnav-background-color, 5%);
            color: #fff;
        }
        a.router-link-active{
            background: darken($topnav-background-color, 5%);
            color: #fff;
        }
    }
    .sidebar-dropdown{
        *:focus{
            border-radius: none;
            border:none;
        }
        .panel-title{
            font-size : 1rem;
            height : 50px;
            margin-bottom:0;
            a{
                color : #999;
                text-decoration : none;
                font-weight:400;
                background:$topnav-background-color;
                span{
                    position: relative;
                    display: block;
                    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
                    padding-top:1rem;
                }
            }
            a:hover,a:focus{
                color: #fff;
                outline: none;
                outline-offset: -2px;
            }
        }
        .panel-title:hover{
            background: darken($topnav-background-color, 5%);
        }
        .panel-collapse{
            border-radious :0;
            border : none;
            .panel-body{
                .list-group-item{
                    border-radius : 0;
                    background-color: $topnav-background-color;
                    border: 0 solid transparent;
                    a{
                        color:#999;
                    }
                    a:hover{
                        color:#FFF;
                    }
                }
                .list-group-item:hover{
                    background : darken($topnav-background-color, 5%);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.bg-white {
    background: #fff;
}
.main-container{
  margin: 50px 0 0 225px;
    padding: 10px;
    -ms-overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.chat-panel{
    .chat-dropdown{
        margin-top: -3px;
    }
    .chat{
        .left{
            img{
                margin-right: 15px;
            }
        }
        .right{
            img{
                margin-left: 15px;
            }
        }
        height: 350px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        li{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
        }   
    }
    .card-footer{
        input{  
            padding : 3px;
        }
    }
}
/* RTL ashboard */
.sidebarPushRight{
    left: 225px !important;
    z-index:10;
}
.mainContainerPushLeft{
    margin : 55px 255px 0 0;
}
/* End */

.display-sm{
    display:none;
}
.hide-sm{
    display:block;
}

@media (min-width: 0){
    .navbar-toggleable-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav{
        .text-center{
            a{
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #toggle-sidebar{
        display:block;
    }
    .topnav{
        .text-center{
            padding-left : 55px;
        }
    }
    .top-right-nav{
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .show-name{
        display: block !important;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .display-sm {
        display:block;
    }
    .hide-sm{
        display:none;
    }
    .sidebar{
        left:0;
    }
    .main-container{
        margin-left : 0;
    }
    .loading {
        left: 39% !important;
    }
}
.carousel {
    .carousel-control{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .carousel-inner {

        .carousel-item{
            img{
                width : 100%;
                max-height : 373px;
            }
        }
        .fa-chevron-left:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 46%;
            left : 50px;
        }
        .fa-chevron-right:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 46%;
            right : 50px;
        }
    }
}

.login-page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: $topnav-background-color;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3em;
    .col-lg-4{
        padding :0;
    }
    .input-lg {
        height: 46px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.3333333;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .input-underline {
        background: 0 0;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .input-underline:focus {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    .rounded-btn{
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
                border-radius: 50px;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        background: $topnav-background-color;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 40px;
        padding: 0 25px;
    }
    .rounded-btn:hover,.rounded-btn:focus,.rounded-btn:active,.rounded-btn:visited{
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
        outline: none;
    }

    h1 {
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 36px;
        small {
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        }
    }

    .form-group {
        padding: 8px 0;
        input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) !important;
        }

        input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) !important;  
        }

        input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) !important;  
        }

        input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
        color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6) !important;  
        }
    }
    .form-content {
        padding: 40px 0;
    }
}
.nested-menu {
    .list-group-item {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nested {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul.submenu {
        height: 0;
    }
    & .expand {
        ul.submenu {
            list-style-type: none;
            height: auto;
            li {
                a {
                    color: #FFF;
                    padding: 10px;
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.spinner {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -55px;
    text-align: center;
}

.spinner > div {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #333;

    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.spinner .bounce1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
    animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinner .bounce2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
    animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
    0%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
    40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
    0%, 80%, 100% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
    } 40% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

**Angular-cli.Json:**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name": "mobile-web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "app.css",
        "animate.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```